# Is there a better way convert an array into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I was told that my codes are inefficient for they use simple loops.

This is my code.

```
const func = () => {

    const idList = {};
    list.forEach((obj) => {
        idList[obj.id] = obj;
    });

    const resultArr = [];

    list.forEach((obj) => {
        const arr = [];
        
        arr.push(obj);
        
        let parent = idList[obj.parentId];
        
        while (parent) {
            arr.unshift(parent);
            parent = idList[parent.parentId];
        };

        resultArr.push(arr);
    });

    return resultArr;
}

const ans = func();

console.log(ans);
```

I think I could use some tiers for those ids that are there as other ids' parentIds, but it is hard to put into codes. It would be so nice to use some help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you're looking for advice on performance or efficiency improvements, please consider moving this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are there that many duplicates in there? That "structure" looks really strange and in-efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Map`, iterate the list, get the "parent" list from the map, add the current object, put the new list back in the map. Return `map.values` when ready.

```
function rows(list) {
    let m = new Map();

    for (let item of list)
        m.set(item.id,
            (m.get(item.parentId) || []).concat([item]));

    return [...m.values()];
}
```

Comment: wow the code is so much shorter than I expected. I have never come across the Map object and related methods! I must work on these new methods. Thank you so much.